# How to force a call to onDrawFrame() on a GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have a UI that haes a GLSurfaceView that shows a polygon.

The UI haves also two buttons ZoomIn and ZoomOut. When the user press these buttons, the zoomIn() and zoomOut() methods of myGLSurfaceView are called.

The problem is that i want that the method onDrawFrame get's called to get reflected the zoom in & out.

Why i want this? because the buttons have setClickable(true); why? because i need that if the user leaves the finger presing the button, the zoom get's applied continuosly until the user releases the buton.

Now it works but it works bad, i need to refresh the GLsurfaceview forcing onDrawFrame

Answer (score -13, accepted):

solved using threads and press/release events of the finger

Comment: How was it solved? That's what acceptable answers demonstrate.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is just a sketch of solution that doesn't have any strong fundament and also uses a bad practice having better options...

Comment: There was no need to tell either you solved this problem or not unless you don't bother to share the appropriate details.

Answer (score 11):

Call [gLSurfaceView.requestRender()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#requestRender%28%29). This will (from link):

> Request that the renderer render a frame. This method is typically used when the render mode has been set to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY, so that frames are only rendered on demand. May be called from any thread. Must not be called before a renderer has been set.

Comment: this is giving black image

Comment: Also getting black images